# Access SQL Query - Top 25 containing /images/

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm a university student (thus a beginner) with some Access tasks to do, but I need help because so far it does not provide the desired result.

I have a table `Table1` containing web log records. My field of interest is "cs-uri-stem", as it contains all the URL GET requests.

I want to select the TOP 25 `images` (records must contain /images/ in the "cs-uri-stem" field). So far I tried the following, with no success:

```
SELECT TOP 25
FROM Table 1
WHERE "cs-uri-stem"="cs-uri-stem"
HAVING [/images/];
```

An alert window keeps appearing saying that the SELECT request is not correct, but I don't know if this is caused by the fact that the Access is in Spanish in my university.

Thanks in advance!

---

Possible answer to my question, provided with Siyual and MCP_infiltrator's help [Thanks again!]:

```
SELECT TOP 25 
   Table1.[cs-uri-stem], 
   Count(Table1.[cs-method]) AS TotalHits 
FROM Table1 
WHERE (((Table1.[cs-uri-stem]) Like '*/images*')) 
GROUP BY Table1.[cs-uri-stem] 
ORDER BY Count(Table1.[cs-method]) DESC`
```

This will provide a top25 list of only the visited images, with no duplicates, instead of all the URLs.

Comment: can you post some example of what the table looks like?

Comment: Table 1 contains fields Id (Primary Key), date, time, s-sitename, s-computername, s-ip, cs-method, cs-uri-stem, cs-uri-query, s-port, cs-username, c-ip, cs-version, cs(User-Agent), ccs(Cookie), cs(Referer), cs-host, cs-status, sc-substatus, sc-win32-status, sc-bytes, cs-bytes, time-taken, with around 50000 records. The thing is I am trying to select the top 25 from a field called cs-uri-stem that contains all the URLs visited, and many of them (but not all) contain image files, following a directory /images/...

Comment: since your column `cs-uri-stem` contains the information you want, use the first answer posted and change `Image` to `cs-uri-stem`

Comment: I did follow Siyual's suggestion (SELECT TOP 25 'cs-uri-stem' FROM Table1 WHERE 'cs-uri-stem' Like '%/images/%'), but when I execute the query then only one field appears, with no results at all, called Expr1000. I'm currently using Access 2007.

Comment: see my answer below using something like `select top 25 *...` might work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your query, but this should work for what you need:

```
SELECT TOP 25 Images
FROM    Table1
WHERE   cs-uri-stem Like '%/images/%'
```

As for the what/why things are wrong...

For your `Select` statement, you aren't specifying any fields that you're wanting to get.  I'm assuming by your question that you have a field named `images` that you're wanting to get back.  If it's some other field, change that, or just use `SELECT TOP 25 *` to get everything.

Your `From` clause has a space in the table name.

Your `Where` clause makes no sense.  This is where you need to be putting your logic for your query.  In this case, you want anything that has `/images/` in the `cs-uri-stem` field.  [`Like`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) is the operator you need to use here.

Finally, your [`Having`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) is just plain wrong.  It's not used correctly, nor is it even in the right context.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's still not working. Apparently something is missing, since the only result for SELECT TOP 25 'cs-uri-stem' FROM Table1 WHERE 'cs-uri-stem' Like '%/images/%' gives a one-field result named Expr1000, with no results in it. I will try again, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 25 *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CS-URI-STEM LIKE "*/images*"
```

This will select the top 25 records and all columns from the table where the `cs-uri-stem` has `/images` in it. When you use the `*` that is telling the db that you want all the columns of the table to be pulled for viewing.

Here is a link describing some of it 
[See Here: Select Top `n` in MS-Access](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/accessquerysql/select_top.htm)

Another link
[from office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx)

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you suggest, and it is still not working. Instead of Expr1000, it then shows all the original fields but no records at all (so I assume the query is wrong). Sorry for the trouble, and I appreciate your help!

Comment: intersting...what version of MS-Access are you using? It should not matter but I'm interested

Comment: instead of the `%` try it the way it is now with the `*` on each side

Comment: Alright, so it worked! Thank you so much!!! Using Access 2007, I created the query SELECT TOP 25 * FROM Table1 WHERE [cs-uri-stem] Like '*/images*' and it returned the result I was looking for. Thank you so much for your effort and patience!

Answer (score 0):

I would create three queries:

query1:

```
SELECT Images
FROM    Table1
WHERE   cs-uri-stem Like '*/images/*'
```

query2:

```
select images, count(images) as image_count
from query1 as q
group by images
```

query3:

```
select top 25 *
from query2
order by image_count desc
```

query3 should have the 25 results that you're interested in.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 25 * FROM Table1 WHERE cs-uri-stem LIKE '%/images/%'
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: If you believe this is the correct answer, can you elaborate on why, instead of just posting code?